# Overloaded operator std::ostream& operator<< prints instance memory address

Tags: c++

I'm trying to overload `std::ostream& operator<<` doing this:

```
#include <iostream>

class MyTime
{
private:
    unsigned char _hour;
    unsigned char _minute;
    float _second;
    signed char _timeZone;
    unsigned char _daylightSavings;
    double _decimalHour;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const MyTime&);
public:
    MyTime();
    ~MyTime();
};
```

And operator's implementation:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &strm, const MyTime &time)
{
    return strm << (int)time._hour << ":" << (int)time._minute << ":" << time._second << " +" << (int)time._daylightSavings << " zone: " << (int)time._timeZone << " decimal hour: " << time._decimalHour;
}
```

But when I do this:

```
MyTime* anotherTime = new MyTime(6, 31, 27, 0, 0);
std::cout << "Time: " << anotherTime << std::endl;
```

It only prints `anotherTime` memory address.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You meant:

```
std::cout << "Time: " << *anotherTime << std::endl;
```

Or, even better:

```
MyTime anotherTime (6, 31, 27, 0, 0);
std::cout << "Time: " << anotherTime << std::endl;
```

Comment: Or probably `MyTime anotherTime(6, 31, 27, 0, 0);`

Comment: @juanchopanza Yeah, definitely.

Answer (score 3):

Your operator expects an instance object by const reference but you're giving it a pointer. Either do `std::cout << "Time: " << *anotherTime << std::endl;` (note the `*`) or add another operator:

`friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const MyTime*);`

Answer (score 1):

```
std::cout << "Time: " << anotherTime << std::endl;
```

in that code above anotherTime instance is a myTime*, but it must be myTime.

You have two solutions to fix this:

Making myTime on stack, and it will work fine because anotherTime now not a pointer.

```
MyTime anotherTime(6, 31, 27, 0, 0);
    std::cout << "Time: " << anotherTime << std::endl;
```

dereference the pointer in your code, like this:

```
MyTime* anotherTime = new MyTime(6, 31, 27, 0, 0);
std::cout << "Time: " << *anotherTime << std::endl;
```